# How do I remove an event listener from an anonymous component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, listeners

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flash AS3 how do I remove stage event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584787/flash-as3-how-do-i-remove-stage-event-listeners)

Say I have an event listener tied to a component and I want to remove the event listener from the component so it can be garbage collected. The problem is I don't know what kind of object it is or what event listeners it has.

Basically how can I find out what event listeners an object has and how can I remove one or all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate.

When you add the event listener mark it as a weak refernce by setting the last parameter as true. You no longer need to worry about removing it. I posted a longish answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584787/flash-as3-how-do-i-remove-stage-event-listeners/585004#585004), so you may want to take a look.